Cant prerespond to a request with fiddler and mark it as done in c#
I tried everything this is the code right now
private static void BeforeRequest(Session session)
{
    session.bBufferResponse = true;


        if (session.uriContains("productlisting/list"))
        {
            session.utilSetResponseBody(fastResponseProductListingList);
            session.bypassGateway = true;
        }
        else if (session.uriContains("productlisting/list/tag"))
        {
            session.utilSetResponseBody(fastResponseStoreProductListingTag);
            session.bypassGateway = true;
        }
        else if (session.uriContains("live/item/listall"))
        {
            session.utilSetResponseBody(fastResponseItemListAll);
            session.bypassGateway = true;
        }
        else if (session.uriContains("live/store/list"))
        {
            session.utilSetResponseBody(fastResponseStoreList);
            session.bypassGateway = true;
        
    }
}

It should work I also hooked up the BeforeRequest but the game still takes long to launch indicating that it didnt auto respond i assume? can anyone help
Explained in the above

I see a logical issue.  'productlisting/list' is a subset of 'productlisting/list/tag', your second branch will never logically trigger, because it will always trigger the first one.  Just need to switch the order.  As for not appearing to get hit, we'll need to know more about where/how events are triggered that call this method.  Lots of breakpoints where you define your event listeners will give you a better idea of the order of operations things are executing, and possibly this method's calling event is being missed.

@Kevin thank you for that i really didn't see that i might just check for the complete url instead but even if i answer like it answers cause i saw the game messing up cause it has wrong data but it still takes long when i launch the game cause the server is in thailand and the server is slow so launching the game takes forever thats why i want to prerespond at least with the stuff thats by default the same is there a way to tell the request its done? like really done cause im pretty sure the game is still waiting for a response even tho i already set the responsebody at beforerequest

Start with break points and step through.  You might have something executing synchronously and it's blocking everything after while waiting for a response.  Without more of your code to look at, finding the specific blocker(s) is not possible.

You want to use the utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer method to set the response body and move the session state to skip talking to the server at all.

Sorting was wrong and also the preloaded data didn't load causing the Game to fail show anything.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
